# Is it possible to overwrite the HttpClient in the MatIconRegistry in Angular?

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-universal

I am using the MatIconRegistry to register a series of SVG icons. 
I am also using Angular Universal to do server side rendering.

Unfortunately, when the registry registers an icon, it's using HttpClient to request the SVG, but unfortunately this request is being repeated again on the client side.

I have my own HttpService that is taking care of transfering the state and avoiding duplicated requests.

Would it be possible to overwrite the HttpClient or to overwrite the addSvgIcon method of the MatIconRegistry so that I can store the requests in my TransferState service?

Comment: Did you take a look at TransferHttpCacheModule ? https://github.com/angular/universal/blob/master/docs/transfer-http.md